# How is an Instance linked to Formal Parameter (or inferred) in Anonymous Class Method in Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, parameter-passing, instantiation, anonymous-class

I am trying to understand how parameter **`driver`** *(from method `apply` in anonymous class `ExpectedCondition`)* gets a **`WebDriver`** instance.

```
package org.openqa.selenium.support.ui;
public class ExpectedConditions {
    public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> javaScriptThrowsNoExceptions(final String javaScript) {
        return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                try {
                    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(javaScript);
                    return true;
                } catch (WebDriverException e) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return String.format("js %s to be executable", javaScript);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

---

```
package org.openqa.selenium.support.ui;
public interface ExpectedCondition<T> extends Function<WebDriver, T> {}
```

---

So far, I acknowledge that (as shown on the code below) I explicitly instantiate `WebDriver` which is used by `WebDriverWait` which ultimately invokes the anonymous class' method that, assuming, will use the `WebDriver` instance that was explicitly created.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.javaScriptThrowsNoExceptions("javascript:void(0);"));
```

I understand that an anonymous class has access to the members of its enclosing scope but I don´t see how that can be applied here.

I also know that, at least when it's about generics, Java performs some inference mechanisms to perform type checking, to decide on what method to execute, etc., so I don´t know if I am missing something important in the big picture or maybe there´s something going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Your anonymous class is not accessing your driver variable. What is happening is that inside the `until` method of your `WebDriverWait`, it is passing `driver` to your `ExpectedCondition`'s apply method. It would be exactly the same if you moved the class outside your method.

Comment: I really missed it, thanks! As you mentioned, the `until` method is doing the job `V value = isTrue.apply(input);` , feeling silly :)